# Class variable is not shared with class instances

Tags: python, class, object, variables, nonetype

I read that class variables are shared between all instances. But I tried this in Python terminal and it doesn't work this way.

What am I misunderstanding here?

It seems that class variables are just used only when new object is created. Is it true?

```py
>>> class A():
...     b=None
...
>>> z=A()
>>> z.b
>>> z.b=1
>>> z.b
1
>>> A.b
>>> A.b=2
>>> A.b
2
>>> z.b  
1         # expected to be 2 instead of 1
>>> x=A()
>>> x.b
2
>>> x.__dict__
{}
>>> z.__dict__
{'b': 1}
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'b': 2, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>>
```

Comment: if its class variable try you use with classname.variable name. ex. A.b , you have created object and for every object it will have different values

Comment: You are shadowing the class variables when you assign to them on the instance: `z.b=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create an instance of `A` and try and read the `b` attribute it will return the class variable because no instance variable exists:

```
>>> class A():
...     b='class'
>>> z = A()
>>> z.b
'class'
```

When you assign a value to `z.b` you are creating an **instance** variable with the name `b` which shadows the class variable:

```
>>> class A():
...     b='class'
>>> z = A()
>>> z.b = 'instance'
>>> z.b
'instance'
```

If you want to access the class variable regardless of whether an instance variable with the same name exists, you can use `__class__`:

```
>>> class A():
...     b='class'
>>> z = A()
>>> z.b = 'instance'
>>> z.b
'instance'
>>> z.__class__.b
'class'
```